# In RoR how can I set the default file DirectoryIndex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, webrick

In Apache I can use DirectoryIndex to specify different files or extensions to be the default served--how do I accomplish this with RoR? In the public directories I have a few folders that need to serve JS files as the index.

With Apache, I'd do:

```
DirectoryIndex index.js
```

I'm using WEBrick locally and Heroku for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a controller that loaded in the JS, like

```
def show
  output = File.read("public/js/stats/index.js")
  render :text => output
end
```

Then I created a route

```
match 'stats/index' => 'stats#show'
```

May not be the most elegant, but I think it was easier than managing dependencies between local and production environments

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this with Heroku unless you use something like [rack_rewrite](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-rewrite)

Comment: +1 for info enlightening me on rack_rewrite--that'll come in handy one day